# operator== of a type erased container

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, type-erasure

Consider the following class that wraps a *container* and *type-erase*s its type:

```
class C final {
    struct B {
        virtual bool empty() const noexcept = 0;
    };

    template<class T, class A>
    struct D: public B {
        // several constructors aimed to
        // correctly initialize the underlying container

        bool empty() const noexcept override { return v.empty(); }

    private:
        std::vector<T, A> v;
    };

    // ...

public:
    //...

    bool operator==(const C &other) const noexcept {
        // ??
        // would like to compare the underlying
        // container of other.b with the one
        // of this->b
    }

private:
    // initialized somehow
    B *b;
};
```

I'd like to add the `operator==` to the class `C`.
Internally, it should simply invoke the same operator on the underlying containers, but I'm stuck on this problem, for I don't know how to do that.
The idea is that two instances of `C` are equal if the `operator==` of their underlying containers return `true`.

Whatever I've tried till now, I ever ended up being unable to get the type of one of the two underlying containers, mainly the one of *other*.
Is there an easy solution I can't see at the moment or I should give up?

Comment: Please model you data properly (your nested classes look like nested namespaces)

Comment: I'd like to help you, but I'd lie saying that I've understood what's wrong with my snippet. I'm sorry. It's well formatted, so what's exactly the problem? I forgot a `;`, that's fixed indeed.

Comment: We're missing the connection between `operator==` and the "class that wraps a container and ...". `class C` has no containers.

Comment: Uhm, you are right, wait, I'm going to add more details...

Comment: Anyway, type-erased iterators and `std::equal`.

Comment: At construction time store a pointer to a function which will do the comparison - the actual function being a suitable template.

Comment: @juanchopanza I got it, the idea is to abstract away even from the containers, for their types can be different, but the types of their contents are not. Am I wrong? Really interesting. Thank you.

Comment: That's the idea. Pick the lowest common denominator type of iteration you want to support, and expose only that. See [this article](https://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html) for a description on why and how to implement an `any_iterator`.

Comment: So good a suggestion. I'll try for myself and post and answer. Once it will be there, please, criticize it if needed!! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the good suggestion from *juanchopanza*, I found that, as far as the underlying containers represent the same concept (as an example, different specializations of a vector), maybe there is no need of a *type-erase*d iterator.

Below it's a possible implementation that relies on the `operator[]` and the `size` member method:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

class Clazz final {
    struct BaseContainer {
        virtual std::size_t size() const noexcept = 0;
        virtual int operator[](std::size_t) const = 0;
        virtual void push_back(int) = 0;
    };

    template<class Allocator>
    struct Container: public BaseContainer {
        Container(Allocator alloc): v{alloc} { }
        std::size_t size() const noexcept override { return v.size(); }
        int operator[](std::size_t pos) const override { return v[pos]; }
        void push_back(int e) override { v.push_back(e); }

    private:
        std::vector<int, Allocator> v;
    };

public:
    template<class Allocator = std::allocator<int>>
    Clazz(const Allocator &alloc = Allocator{})
        : container{new Container<Allocator>{alloc}} { }

   ~Clazz() { delete container; }

    void push_back(int e) { container->push_back(e); }

    bool operator==(const Clazz &other) const noexcept {
        const BaseContainer &cont = *container;
        const BaseContainer &oCont = *(other.container);
        bool ret = (cont.size() == oCont.size());

        for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0, s = cont.size(); i < s && ret; i++) {
            ret = (cont[i] == oCont[i]);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Clazz &other) const noexcept {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

private:
    BaseContainer *container;
};

int main() {
    Clazz c1{}, c2{}, c3{};
    c1.push_back(42);
    c2.push_back(42);
    assert(c1 == c2);
    assert(c1 != c3);
}
```

Open to criticism, hoping this answer can help other users. :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza I expect at least a comment of yours on this snippet!! :-)

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you wish to return false when the comparing two different containers, this should do the job (caution: untested):

```
class Container
{
    struct Concept
    {
        virtual ~Concept() = default;
        virtual Concept* clone() const = 0;

        virtual bool equals(Concept const*) const = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Model final : Concept
    {
        Model(T t) : data{std::move(t)} {}
        Model* clone() const override { return new Model{*this}; }

        virtual bool equals(Concept const* rhs) const override
        {
            if (typeid(*this) != typeid(*rhs))
                return false;

            return data == static_cast<Model const*>(rhs)->data;
        }

        T data;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Concept> object;

public:
    template<typename T>
    Container(T t) : object(new Model<T>{std::move(t)}) {}

    Container(Container const& that) : object{that.object->clone()} {}
    Container(Container&& that) = default;

    Container& operator=(Container that)
    { object = std::move(that.object); return *this; }

    friend bool operator==(Container const& lhs, Container const& rhs)
    { return lhs.object->equals(rhs.object.get()); }
};
```

Comment: The problem is that `static_cast` could result in an undefined behavior if the underlying model is not the same for both the container, so to derefer the resulting instance could lead to a crash. Moreover, the cast to `Model` as it stands leads probably to a compilation error.

Comment: No, it cannot.  The typeid check before it ensures that the static_cast is defined behavior.  I also get no compilation error with clang.  Given that Model is declared final, you can also use dynamic_cast.

Comment: Anyway, this solution does not allow to use different containers (vector, list, and so on) and compare their contents. As an example, I would like the `Model`s to be equal fi they have the same size and the same items, no matter if they are of different types.

Comment: In general that is not solvable with type erasure, even if you type erase the iterators (which is a significant performance penalty).  You have to add constraints (such as only compare containers of type T), as code for the concrete comparisons has to be generated somewhere.